# Количество пробелов в строке

Tags: c++

Нужно посчитать кол-во пробелов в строке. Не могу понять что и как. Застрял на вводе самой строки. Выводится лишь первое слово.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    char str[140];

    cout<<"Введите ваш текст:\n";
    cin>>str;

    cout<<str<<endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: @inferus-vv читайте документацию

     std::operator>> (string)

     Extracts a string from the input stream is, storing the sequence in str, which is overwritten (the previous value of str is replaced).
     ...
     Notice that the istream extraction operations use whitespaces as separators; Therefore, this operation will only extract what can be considered a word from the stream. To extract entire lines of text, see the string overload of global function getline.

Comment: @inferus-vv, просто вместо >> вызывайте функцию getline().

Comment: @avp: Можно воспользоваться тем, что `>>` читает до пробела, и просто подсчитать количество вызовов `>>` до конца файла `cin`. Но это не сработает со сдвоенными пробелами.

Comment: @VladD, не получится. 

При чтении >> невозможно определить какой был разделитель (пробел, табуляция, ньюлайн...) и сколько их было подряд.

Comment: @avp: Угу. Но так можно было бы подсчитать количество _слов_.

Comment: @VladD, да. Но опять же не в строке, а во всем файле.

Comment: Хм, а как насчет решения с использованием strtok() ? Ну, а в крайнем случае ведь можно и просто в цикле читать посимвольно строку, сразу же делая при этом подсчет пробелов и прочих space-симолов.

Comment: @0xFFh, вот-вот -- подсчитать в цикле.

Проблема же у ТС а чтении **целой** строки.

Еще можно просто читать по одному символу и подсчитывать пробелы, а при обнаружении `'\n'` печатать и сбрасывать счетчик.

Только вот оператор >> тут опять не применим. В ьаклм случае надо вызывать `cin.get()`

Comment: Страсти какие.

     #include <iostream>
     #include <sstream>
     using namespace std;

     int main(int argc, char *argv[])
     {
       string words = "word1 word2   word3   word4       ";
       istringstream str(words);
       int i=0;
       while (!str.eof()) {
         string s;
         str >> s;
         cout << (++i) << ':' << str.good() << ' ';
         cout << s.length() << ':'  << s << endl;
       }
     }


    1:1 5:word1
    2:1 5:word2
    3:1 5:word3
    4:1 5:word4
    5:0 0:


Ну если строка заканчивается на слове, то good() == 0 будет на нём

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `std::getline` чтобы прочитать всю строку:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    std::cout << "Введите ваш текст:\n";

    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

    std::cout << std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ') << '\n';
}
```